# How would I turn a phase transition chart into a 2D array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, charts, physics

I am trying to make a C# program that will take input for temperature(double) and pressure(also double) and output the phase the material is in(string) via a 2D array, but it is impossible to write every pressure and temperature combination in a 2D array, while still being precise. ex:

|  | 0K | 0.01k |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **0 atm** | SOLID | SOLID |
| **0.01 atm** | SOLID | SOLID |

Another, perhaps simpler, example is getting the color of an image based on coordinates. here is some pseudocode.

```cs
public string getColor(int x, int y)
{
    return (x, y).color of the image;
}
```

Other than using a super complicated 2D array, i have no clue how to do this.
Is there a way to automate the
array being created, or a better way to do this?

```cs
public string getState(double temperature, double pressure){
    return the string at (temperature, pressure) on the phase diagram;
}
```

If I need to be more clear, please tell me.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Seems you're looking more for a formula than an array. What is the input data you have?

Comment: It seems that you are looking for *interpolation*: linear (the simplest), cubic (probably, the most popular). Having points in (p, t) you can represent a curve of phase transition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation

Comment: There's no need to have a 2d array of points. Have a look at phase diagram: there are just three simple lines (if we are looking just for gas/liquid/solid; if focus on solid, i.e. crystal lattice we can have more than 20 different states, e.g. ice-I, ice-II, ..., ic-XIX for water). Having all these lines interpolated you can easily answer what state it is: above gas-liquid, but right to liquid-solid line, so we have a liquid etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram